# Connections and requests values for load testing

Tags: linux, httperf

I want to apply some load testing to my web (remote) server, actually I have tried Httperf with Autobench, but I don't have the knowledge to know what values to use for the number of connections and number of requests/seg.

So I have 2 questions:

1) What are values that you recommend me to try for number of connections and number of requests

2) Are these values limited by the bandwith of the internet connection from where I am doing the tests? I have a 1Mbps/256Kbps connection :(

Comment: How long is a piece of string?  Your testing should reflect real-world values, which vary too widely to provide a rule of thumb.  If you're Akami and you're doing load testing, you might want to test at hundreds or thousands of Gbps.  That's probably not so applicable to your webserver, though.

Answer (score 1):

1) we can't tell. You need to test with the load you expect to have, and you will see if your server can process that load, and in what time.

2) Yes they are, mostly by your upload. Latency will be longer because of your limited upload speed.